# Linq from XML to Object with one Element ToList<>

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to perform a LINQ Query on an xml document.  The output should be a list of type Quiz.  One of the members of the object is also a list but it is List of type string.  The code works for everything but the one element that needs to be put into a List of type string.  I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find the right syntax for this scenario.

The Code looks something like this.

```
public static List<Quiz> QuizBuilder()
    {
        XDocument data = XDocument.Load("Data.xml");
        List<Quiz> newquiz = (from d in data.Descendants("Object")
                              select new Quiz(
                                          (string)d.Element("Question"),
                                          (string)d.Element("Answer"),
                                       //This next line does not work
                                          (List<string>)d.Elements("Choice")
                                          )).ToList();
        return newquiz;
    }
```

the xml looks something like this.

```
 <Root>
    <Object>
       <Question>Question 1</Question>
       <Answer>a</Answer>
       <Choice>a</Choice>
       <Choice>b</Choice>
       <Choice>c</Choice>
       <Choice>d</Choice>
    </Object>
 </Root>
```

the code doesn't show any errors till run time then I get a casting error when the code is run.
Unable to cast object of type 'd__11' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't work"*? What doesn't work

Comment: I get a casting error at run time.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type '<GetElements>d__11' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'.

Comment: [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351784(v=vs.110).aspx) return `IEnumerable<XElement>`, so you need just something like `d.Elements("Choice").Select(i=>i.Value).ToList()`

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to mark "Grudy's" answer as the correct one.

Comment: @evilsushi you can mark @EZI answer, it same with my comment, because `XElement` has [Explicit Conversion (XElement to String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You can not cast `d.Elements("Choice")` to `List<string>`

Use this

```
Choices = d.Elements("Choice").Select(x=>(string)x).ToList()
```

instead of

```
(List<string>)d.Elements("Choice")
```

Comment: Yours was close but I was still getting a different error.  The correct code ended up being "Grundy's"  Thank you anyhow.

Comment: it says an object reference is required for a non-static field method or property.

Comment: @evilsushi There is no code in your question(and in my answer) that can result in such an compilation error. This will not be the first time you get such compilation errors in your programming life. How about learning how to debug/fix your code? BTW: I am really curious about a case where Grundy's code can work and this fails. Just post it if you can reproduce it.

Comment: This is actually a pre-compilation error.  I tried modifying your code to get it to work but I couldn't get the error to clear.  I tried the code again and it still gives the same error even after attempting a build.  While I am still a fairly novice programmer, I do attempt to debug/fix my code before coming on here, however, there is only so much I can learn from books and websites with out asking for some assistance.